# HTML pattern attribute not working when checked in database

Tags: php, regex, html

Hi everybody i have a form in index.html. Following are two code snippets, please have a look and help me sort out the issue mentioned at the end of this question . Thank you

```
<form method="post" action="subscribe.php" class="contactform center-block">

        <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-6">
           <!-- <label for="userName">Name</label>-->
            <input
                   name="fullName" 
                   type="text" 
                   class="form-control"
                   pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,}" 
                   id="userName" 
                   placeholder="Enter your Full Name here" 
                   required
            >

        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
                <input 
                     type="submit" 
                     name="submit" 
                     id="submit1" 
                     value="Subscibe!"
                     class="submitBtn btn btn-primary ">
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

and here is **subscribe.php**

```
<?php 

 if(!empty($_POST)) {

$mysqli = new mysqli(
    'localhost',
    'username',
    'password',
    'dbname'
);


$admin = 'example@hello.com';
$useremail = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "My Subject";
$username = $_POST['fullName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$header = 'From ' . $email;

$message = <<<EMAIL

  message body.....

EMAIL;



// Check for connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}


//Insert our data

$sql = "INSERT INTO subscribe(fullName,email)VALUES(

'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fullName'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string(($_POST['email']))}' )";

// Print Response from MySql

if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {

    if(mail( $admin , $subject , $message, $header)){
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

    }

 } else {

    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
 }

 // Close the connection

 $mysqli->close();

 }


 ?>
```

**Issue**

MySql Database is connected and working properly, data is inserted but the problem lies when i look at **subscribe table** in DB and **fullName column** still contains row having value like this **59c29dc55ff88** even i have mentioned the pattern in input tag in html form above . It works correctly in web page but when i look in DB the value is shown in the format i have mentioned. I am worried how someone can insert this type of data in name input when pattern attribute is mentioned already .

Please guide me . Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi The structure type of your fullName column is?

Comment: It is maybe problem in your `fullName` column structure type. Can you tell what is that? 
And obviously you must verify everything on server side beside client side. Cause client side can be easily manipulated

Comment: VARCHAR type and length 60 in DB

Comment: Does your browser support HTML5?

Comment: I am removing the mysql tag since this is an html question; `<inp ... pattern ...>` involves html, not database.

Comment: Just so you know, client-side validation is not going to prevent people from inserting whatever they like.

Comment: @RickJames Yes of course latest version google chrome supports HTML5.

Comment: @Marty Thanks , what could be the server side validation for it

Comment: In PHP, you would use (for example) `preg_match('/.../', $_POST[...])` to compare the data entry to a regexp.  Then spit at the user in some way that could be more involved than what little HTML5 can do.

Comment: Let me try it whether it works or not!